# How to create a internal table based on object attribute?

Tags: oop, abap

I am trying to create sorted table based on instances.
Here below my coding :

```
CLASS my_fancy_pony DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    DATA mv_nice_key TYPE i.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS my_fancy_pony IMPLEMENTATION.
ENDCLASS.


DATA lt_my_fancy_ponys TYPE SORTED TABLE OF REF TO my_fancy_pony WITH UNIQUE KEY mv_nice_key.
DATA lt_my_fancy_ponys TYPE SORTED TABLE OF REF TO my_fancy_pony WITH UNIQUE KEY table_line->mv_nice_key.
```

This is not passing through the syntax check.
Could you tell how I can achieve that?

Comment: You just can't do that. The closest solution for a sorted or hashed table, is to create a table with two components, one being the instance and one being for the attribute, and you can then define the key on this second component (note that the value will be redundant --the attribute and the component-- but that's the only solution).

Comment: I do it like Sandra but it's pretty limited... you can't use LOOP with WHERE condition on anything but the key for example. I would like ABAP to support using public attributes of an instance as structure components when looping or using table expressions with references.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use classes directly as structures.

However, you can construct a map that does what you need:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF map_entry,
    mv_nice_key   TYPE i,
    ref_to_object TYPE REF TO my_fancy_pony,
  END OF map_entry.

TYPES map_type TYPE SORTED TABLE OF map_entry WITH UNIQUE KEY mv_nice_key.

DATA(lt_my_fancy_pony_map) = VALUE map_type(
  FOR each IN lt_my_fancy_ponys
    ( mv_nice_key   = each->mv_nice_key
      ref_to_object = each ) ).
```

The map can number any of the class's attributes that you need:

```
TYPES:
  BEGIN OF map_entry,
    mv_nice_key    TYPE i,
    some_other_att TYPE i,
    " ...
    ref_to_object  TYPE REF TO my_fancy_pony,
  END OF map_entry.

TYPES map_type TYPE SORTED TABLE OF map_entry WITH NON-UNIQUE KEY table_line.

DATA(lt_my_fancy_pony_map) = VALUE map_type(
  FOR each IN lt_my_fancy_ponys
    ( mv_nice_key    = each->mv_nice_key
      some_other_att = each->some_other_att 
      " ...
      ref_to_object  = each ) ).
```